# How to total values in a row in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with some values and I want to total these values; however, the values are in different columns (2A, 2B, 2C, etc.)

Using VBA in Excel, how do I calculate the sum of the cells in the row? All solutions I have searched for show me how to calculate values in a column.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers you got below ? any feedback for people who spent time to assist you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (explanations inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumRow()

Dim LastCol As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet2") ' modify to your sheet's name
    LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get last column with data in row 2

    ' put the SUM result in Cell A3
    .Cells(3, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, LastCol))
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop goes through any pre-selected  column range and adds every value within a row together.

```
    Dim columnCount AS integer
    Dim total AS long

    columnCount = 12345 'the amount of column you want to play with
    total = 0 'the total you are looking for

    For i= 1 to columnCount
      total = total + cells(2,i).value
    Next i  '
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no error values in the row then just sum all the values in the row - no need to find the last column.

`Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(2))`